# Using Javascript to hide text shown on currency switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to use `Javascript` (on page load) to remove the wording '`Choose a currency to display the price:`'.

Leaving just the currency icons in the box (`Div id = currency-switch`).

How can I do this?

**Page url**: http://www.workbooks.com/pricing-page

**Image example**:

[image]

Comment: you want to do it on a click event, or just when page is loaded?

Comment: `document.getElementById('currency-switch').childNodes[0].remove();`, would be the vanilla-JS solution. When exactly should this be called?

Comment: Apologies on page load. Now edited.

Comment: On document ready solution with jQuery below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove this text with for example:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var el = document.getElementById("currency-switch");
    var child = el.childNodes[0];
    el.removeChild(child);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, when will this be called?

Comment: it should be called on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below which will just remove the text:

This will trigger on page load

```
<script>

// self executing function here

  (function() {
    var selected_div = document.getElementById('currency-switch');
    var text_to_change = selected_div.childNodes[0];
    text_to_change.nodeValue = '';
  })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it stupid simple just add an span around the text and give it an id like "currency_text".
Then you only need this code:

```
var elem = document.getElementByid("currency_text");
elem.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks unfortunately this is unsuitable as I can't easily edit the text

Comment: Why is an ID even necessary in this case?!

Comment: It's not necessary but it's idiot proof. After a couple months you will be smashing your head on your desk while finding out why your text is suddenly is beging removed from the DOM. With my solution you could find the string "currency_text" in your js files. I would not recommend DOM manipulation by accessing childnodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currencyDiv = $('#currency-switch');
    currencyDiv.innerHTML(currencyDiv.innerHTML().replace("Choose a currency to display the price:", ""));
}
```

This will remove the text as soon as the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a text node, you could do the following in `jQuery`. This will be triggered on `DOM` ready.

```
$(function() {
    jQuery("#currency-switch").contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var requiredContent = document.getElementById('currency-switch').innerHTML.split(':')[1];
document.getElementById('currency-switch').innerHTML = requiredContent;
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/eg4hpg4z/

However, it is not very clean, but should work, if you cant directly modify the html.

A better solution would be to modify your code to move the text content within a span and show hide the text like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="currency-switch">
    <span class="currency-label">Choose a currency to display the price: </span>
    <span class="gb-background"><span class="GB"> £ </span></span><span class="es-background"><span class="ES"> € </span></span><span class="au-background"><span class="AU"> $ </span></span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('currency-label')[0].style.display = 'none';
```